# Can not use Wacom Intuos CTL-480 and Touch Tablet on Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, usb, tablet, wacom

I am extremely new to Linux and just recently downloaded Ubuntu to my Chromebook. I really need to install my **Wacom Intuos Pen** and **Touch tablet** but the system can not recognize it. I  have already gone through the terminal and used codes and such, but always got a negative response. I'm not very good when it comes to working in the terminal, is it possible that there is any other way I can install said tablet?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu did you install?

Comment: @Akiva 12.04. Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Yes; the first thing I would do is to install 14.04. Chrome books are a recent technology, so getting the newest software stack has a high chance of solving your problems. If it works, please tell me, I'll provide it as an answer, and you can accept it so other users know what to do. Good luck.

Comment: @Akiva How exactly would I update it? Sorry I'm a Linux noob. v n v

Comment: Good question. There are two ways. An Upgrade, or a Fresh Install. Both are officially supported, but a Fresh Install in my opinion is the best; it just takes a bit more effort.  To upgrade (The easy and quick way), http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-12-04 -- To do a fresh install, http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: @Akiva I went to the first website link, the one about the LTE to LTE update. I wish to do that one, but when I typed in the command showed it wouldn't work. It just says "command not found". Any idea why?

Comment: "sudo update-manager -d"?

Comment: http://irc.lc/freenode/ubuntu/t4nk@@@ you can go here for live help; they will guide you through the process through a chat window.

Comment: The ch-480 will work from Ubuntu 14.04 out of the box. On older versions you need to modify the kernel which is a advanced process. So keep trying to update to 14.04

Comment: @Akiva Yes, that's the command I use. I continue to get a negative response.

Comment: I'm trying to Install Ubuntu 14.04.1 directly from the Ubuntu website. Let's hope this works..

Comment: @rechengehirn I updated to Ubuntu 14.04. My tablet is still not being recognized by the OS.